# Select rows if a value of a specific field is different from value of that field in previous row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table like this.

[image]

I want to select rows if the value field of that row is different from value field of previous row. In other word, in the sample table, I want to get these rows : 1,2,3,6,7. How I can do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the **lag** function in goal to get the previous value for each row.

In your case:

```
select * 
from (
select parameter, value, year, LAG(value, 1) 
over (order by your_order_by_column) pre_value from T_TABLE)
where pre_value <> value;
```

Comment: Add `or pre_value is null` in order to get the first row, too.

Comment: but pre_value can be null because the preavious row value is actually null. so if there are 2 close rows with value null, the second one will appear. even it shouldn't. another condition required.

Comment: If `value` is nullable, then one will have to define anyway how to treat nulls. The sample data shows no nulls, so I assume there are none.